# SQL Server 2008R2 Management Studio, where are my db objects?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've been working with sql server 2008 exclusively through the visual studio interface since I've started coding. I'm trying to get at my database in the SSMS, and I connect, but my database is visible, but not expandable in the object explorer.. I see an object count of 0 in the object explorer details. In VS, I have a full database heirarchy to work with, dozens of tables, sprocs, functions. The connection string points to the same location. Any ideas? I have RTFM to no avail. :)
[image]

Comment: Are you using "user instances" in your connection string? If so, pointing to "the same location" may be a ruse.

Comment: @Aaron Hello Aaron. I am. Here's the string: @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Market.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=600;User Instance=True" So I have a missing db file it seems?

Comment: No, I just think that the instance of the database you're seeing in VS is not the same instance you're seeing in SSMS. Are you using user instances on purpose?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I had copied that format for a connection string from examples I had found when I created the db. So no, to my understanding of things, I don't have a need by design for user instances, as long as I can use SSMS and C#/ .NET code to access the same db I'm happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my database was awaiting recovery... this was fixed by running the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE Market SET OFFLINE
GO

ALTER DATABASE Market SET ONLINE
GO
```